# iPhone game saves

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How do I save game state in iPhone game? I have it all in NSDictionary. Some say use NSUserDefaults but that seems meant for things like volume. I can't find any official sample code that uses game saves. What is the apple way for saving game state?

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to save the dict as a plist the documents folder, something like this will work:

```
NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString* documentDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString * savePath = [documentDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"save.plist"];
    [dict writeToFile: savePath atomically: YES];
```

Comment: But what if another app want to use a file name of save.plist? it will crash and burn

Comment: Apps cannot see each other's files. They use separate physical locations

Comment: This is a little confusing, on the Mac the Document's directory is the ~/Documents in iOS it is /Applications/someapplicationIdentifier/Documents, check out ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/Someversion

Comment: +1 for plists. I use them for storing client info, and it's quicker than CoreData.

Answer (score 1):

It depends. `NSUserDefaults` are ok for a few or small things, but for larger things you might want to look at CoreData.

Answer (score 1):

If you manage all of your state using Core Data, then you get saving and loading for free.  This is what most iPhone apps use as their data store, and why it exists.

A transition from an NSDictionary to Core Data is straightforward, but you'll need to understand how Core Data works and define your scheme.

NSUserDefaults is **not** supposed to be used to save things like game state, it's to be used to save things like settings.

Comment: Is there any sample for this? My problem is not serializing the data, I can already represent it as string, the problem is where to save it.

Comment: The examples are in: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html    - if you're already serializing the data then you may be too far down the rabbit hole to have Core Data be worthwhile.  I can't answer that question.  But this is the right way to do things from scratch by far.  And Core Data is not going anywhere and is a OSX as well as iOS technology so it's a good skill to have.  You'll need to draw a schema of your data and then use the managed object graph to interact with all your data.

Answer (score 0):

Archiving is used to save object graphs in IOS. You can retrive the complete saved state by archiving it.

Answer (score 0):

There's also [`NSKeyedArchiver`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSKeyedArchiver_Class/Reference/Reference.html) which is more flexible than `NSUserDefaults`, but not as powerful as CoreData.